Mathematical aspects of ciphers: Ask on here or Puzzling.SE?
Question:

Should I ask here or on Puzzling.SE about the mathematical aspects of ciphers?

I have a question about a cipher called the "Prime Multiplication Cipher" which is a cipher that involves converting the letters to numbers using a prime number table and then raising that number to the power of its position in its word.
The method to decoding it is finding the prime factors of the numbers and seeing how many times each number appears. Usually, if a word contains multiple of the same letters, then the word is usually split up. This is to avoid losing the letter's position.
This can usually be avoided by doing the position power letter instead (position as the $n$th  prime number to the letter as converted to A1Z26), but then of course you have the problem of the numbers being super huge super fast.
My question in this case is whether or not there is a fast way to decode this type of cipher. (i.e. How to recognize prime factors quickly)
However, I don't know whether I should post this here (hence I could use the puzzle tag when asking my question) or if it would be considered more on-topic on Puzzling.SE. (since there exists the cipher tag and puzzles involving mathematics are on-topic there)

Posts should not be used to "pose questions for entertainment of the community" as they are at puzzling.se. (See here) but if can frame it as an actual mathematical question you need help solving then you can make a case for it.

Paraphrased from my answer on Puzzling.SE Meta (currently at [+1/-0] at time of posting)

As @rschwieb mentioned in their comment, while posts on Math.SE are not supposed to pose entertainment for the community, if it can be framed as an actual math question that I am having trouble solving, then yes, I can ask it here. Otherwise, it should be asked on Puzzling.SE because the main idea of the site is puzzles in general.

TL;DR:

Yes, if the question can be framed as an actual math problem. (which in that case the question should include the puzzle tag)
No, if it's just a puzzle. (there's no real attempt at trying to solve it) It should then be posted on Puzzling.SE.

